# Periodic solutions of an ODE on a circle.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I am trying to mark some homework solutions. The question is: suppose $\dot{x}=f(x)$, with $x \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$, and $f(x) \neq 0$. Assume existence and uniqueness theorem is satisfied. Is it possible for periodic solutions to exist?

Of course, the answer is that all solutions are periodic since $f(x) \neq 0$ which means $x(t)$ is monotone, and we have $x(t)=x(t) \mbox{mod} 1$. In other words, there exists time period $T>0$ s.t. $x(t,t_{0},x_{0})=x(t+T, t_{0}, x_{0})$, for any initial condition $x(t_{0})=x_{0}$.

However, apparently somebody told the students that we have $x(t,t_{0},x_{0})= x(t+2\pi, t_{0}, x_{0})$.

I am wondering why the apparent statement that $T=2\pi$. To me, the time period $T$ is dependent on the specific form of the solution (or equivalently, the form of $f(x)$).Hence we can't assume a priori that $T=2\pi$. So whoever said that, is making a mistake.

Am I right?

Comment: This depends on how you define or enforce something like $x∈\Bbb S^1=\Bbb T$. Or is it $x∈C^1(\Bbb S^1)$. It is not literally the unit circle, but some periodization of the real line.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it depends how one exactly defines the periodization of the real line. So for example, I could take $x  \mbox{mod} 2\pi$ instead. But my question is different - what I mean is that no matter what periodization of the real line is chosen, you cannot determine what the time period is without some information on the form of $f(x)$?

Comment: I think that the most correct setting for this problem is considering the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$ ($x \in \mathbb{R}$) when $f(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic. But instead of dealing with periodic solutions in sense "exists $T>0$ such that for solution $\gamma(t)$ holds $\gamma(t+T) = \gamma(t)$" we have to consider the property "exists $T > 0$ such that for solution $\gamma(t)$ holds $\gamma(t+T) = \gamma(t) + 2\pi"$. And then $\gamma(t) \; {\rm modd} \; 2\pi$ is periodic.

Comment: Yep, I agree that taking $f(x)$ to be $2\pi$-periodic is the best setting here. So essentially, my statement (in the original question) is correct? Another thing, when we talk about $x \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$, what is the standard period for $x$? Is it always $2\pi$ in this notation? @Evgeny

Comment: Well, no, it hasn't to be always $2\pi$-periodic, I was just lazy and couldn't figure out what letter to use for the spatial period :) Could you clarify what statement are you talking about? Because there are few statements in your question...

Comment: @Alex: I would say you're correct, based on this counter example: take $x(t) = (\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t))$, which is periodic but not with period $2\pi$. It's not difficult to find $f(x)$ such that this $x(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$.

Comment: Ok, but in my original question, we assume the vector field $f(x)$ to be restricted to a circle, where as your example seems to be for $\mathbb{T}^{2}$, right? @FritsVeerman

Comment: My first statement is that for a vector field $f(x)$ on a circle, with $f(x) \neq 0$, there exists $T$  such that $x(t+T)=x(t)$. I  don't see how that is different to your relation  $x(t +T) = x(t) +2\pi$, since we have $x(t) \mbox{mod} 2\pi$ by assumption that we are on a circle. My second statement is that $T$ is only determined by the specific form of the solution (or equivalently the form of $f(x)$). Is this ok? @Evgeny

Comment: The short answer is "yes, you're right, $T$ depends on $f(x)$". If you use the setting that I've suggested there's also an exact formula for period: $T = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{f(x)} $.

Comment: Alex: I agree, I was thinking the same thing after I posted my comment. I've used the standard embedding of $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $f:S^1 \to TS^1 \simeq S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$; then, I used the angle to parametrise $x \in S^1$, i.e. used the canonical chart $S^1 \to [0,2\pi)$. Having all this in mind, I suggest you take the shortcut and adopt the interpretation of @Evgeny, which is equivalent to the above, and describes the problem in a more familiar setting -- with an added bonus of an explicit expression for $T$.